# Jasmine - how to test HttpLoaderFactory from @ngx-translate

Tags: jasmine, code-coverage, ngx-translate

I'm writing Angular app with @ngx-translate dependency so I configured package according to doc:

https://github.com/ngx-translate/core?tab=readme-ov-file#configuration

*app.module.ts*

```js
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { HttpClient, HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { TranslateHttpLoader } from '@ngx-translate/http-loader';
import { TranslateModule, TranslateLoader } from '@ngx-translate/core';

import { AppComponent } from './main';

export function HttpLoaderFactory(http: HttpClient) {
  return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, 'assets/i18n/', '.json');
}

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    TranslateModule.forRoot({
      defaultLanguage: 'en',
      loader: {
        provide: TranslateLoader,
        useFactory: HttpLoaderFactory,
        deps: [HttpClient],
      },
    }),
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Then, my Jasmine code coverage raport says I should test HttpLoaderFactory.

[image]

I am wondering how can I do this? [Code on stackblitz](https://stackblitz-starters-cidkw1.stackblitz.io)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can create a separate describe block, which is just plain jasmine unit testing for this function, to cover this function, we can use the below code.

Its really difficult to test this scenario, so I am initializing the `TranslateHttpLoader` with the same params and comparing the returned value with the intialized value!

```
import { TranslateHttpLoader } from '@ngx-translate/http-loader';

import { HttpLoaderFactory } from './app.module';

describe('should cover HttpLoaderFactory', () => {
  it('should initialize TranslateHttpLoader with params', () => {
    const httpClient = {} as any;
    const returnValue = HttpLoaderFactory(httpClient);
    expect(returnValue).toEqual(
      new TranslateHttpLoader(httpClient, 'assets/i18n/', '.json')
    );
  });
});
```

[<kbd>**`Stackblitz Demo`**</kbd>](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-kcqk4w?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.spec.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts)

Comment: Spy gives me: Error: <spyOnProperty> : TranslateHttpLoader is not declared configurable

Comment: @KamilC. Strange is it possible to reproduce in the stackblitz i shared?

Comment: Sure, please take a look: https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-tmm8vh?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.spec.ts